# Excel - Concatenating cells returned through looking up against duplicate values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup, concatenation

I have a unique problem that I have been unable to solve and hoping to get insights from the experts here. I have the below table:

```
Sprint ID#     Description
1               ABC
1               XYZ
2               DEF
2               HIJ
```

I am trying to now concatenate the values against sprint ID 1 and 2 in a new table where I have the first column as sprint ID (1,2) and the second column the concatenated description ( ABC and XYZ for 1, and DEF and HIJ for 2).

Can someone help guide me through the solution for this?

Comment: I'd use Get&Transform AKA PowerQuery. For example see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44058355/9758194) post on SO

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is cols A:B

Start your new table in D:E

In E2 enter the below as an array formula, (press Ctrl+ SHIFT +ENTER together to make it an array formula)

```
=CONCAT(IF(A2:A5=D2,B2:B5,""))
```

[image]

To add a space inbetween the descriptions use:

```
=CONCAT(IF(A2:A5=D2,B2:B5&" ",""))
```

Or for something else use:

```
=CONCAT(IF(A2:A5=D2,B2:B5&"something else",""))
```

Change the ranges to suit your needs.